# hide table columns which have row span

Tags: html, asp.net

i have a table with 2 rows and 4 columns.first and last td is rowspan="2".
in first column  i have 2 radio buttons. when i click the first one 2nd column should hide and 3rd one should be visible and vice versa. 
since it has rowspan td:nth-child(2)').show() not working properly
please help

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var check = $("#RadioDiv input:radio:checked").val()
   if (check == 'Date Wise') {
     $('#tblmenubar td:nth-child(2)').show();
     $('#tblmenubar td:nth-child(3)').hide();
   } else {
     $('#tblmenubar td:nth-child(2)').hide();
     $('#tblmenubar td:nth-child(3)').show();
   }
   $('#RadioDiv input').click(function() {
     var checktype = $("#RadioDiv input:radio:checked").val()
       // alert(checktype);
     if (checktype == 'Year Wise') {
       $('#tblmenubar td:nth-child(3)').show();
       $('#tblmenubar td:nth-child(2)').hide();
       //alert('year check');
     } else {
       $('#tblmenubar td:nth-child(2)').show();
       $('#tblmenubar td:nth-child(3)').hide();
       //alert('date check');
     }

   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menubar">
  <table id="tblmenubar" border="bold">
    <tr>
      <td align="left" rowspan="2">
        <div id="RadioDiv">
          <input type="radio" name="type" value="Year Wise">Year Wise
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="type" value="Date Wise">Date Wise

          <!-- <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbyeardate" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Year Wise</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Date Wise</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList> -->

        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Start Date:
        <div style="float: right;" id='jqxDateTimeInputstart'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        Year:
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <input id="btntrial" type="button" value="Submitt" />
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>End Date:
        <div style="float: right;" id='jqxDateTimeInputend'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dlFiscalYear" runat="server">
          <asp:ListItem>2013</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <div style="float: left;" id="jqxDropDownListYear">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: yes i am new to SO. i didn't see any green check mark to accept the answer

Comment: Don't worry. I'll try to guide you. There should be a tick (check mark) on the left under the vote arrows of the answer you want to accept. When you click on it, it will turn green to mark that answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Now i got it.Tick will turn to green only after selection. that's lead to me confusion. Now i understood. From now on wards i will TICK if i get the solution to my problem.

Comment: Great. Welcome to the community of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is not that your first and last column are `rowspan="2"`. The `rowspan` attribute affects rows not columns. What happens is that your second row doesn't have 4 columns but 2. You can just add an empty invisible empty cell in the second row to compensate the number of columns before the two you want to show/hide, and, very important, in the same position. Then your `:nth-child()` selector will select the proper cells.

```
<tr>
  <td style="display: none"></td>
  <td>End Date:
    <div style="float: right;" id='jqxDateTimeInputend'>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dlFiscalYear" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem>2013</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <div style="float: left;" id="jqxDropDownListYear">
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```